# unexpected output in copy constructor in the following code

Tags: c++

```
#include < iostream >

using namespace std;

class A
{

      public:
           int x;
           A(int i)
           {

            x= i;
            cout<<"Constructor is Called "<<x<<endl;
          }
          ~A()
           {
            cout<<"destructor is Called "<<x<<endl;
           }

          A(const A &a)
          {
                cout<<"in copy constructor a.x = "<<a.x<<endl;
                cout<<" x = "<<x<<endl;
          }
      };

      const A &fun(int i)
      {
          cout<<"in Fun"<<endl;
          A t(i+1);
          return(t);
      }

     main()
     {
          A *gg = new A(5);
          A t = fun(2);
     }
```

**output of this is :**

```
Constructor is Called 5  
in Fun  
Constructor is Called 3  
destructor is Called 3  
in copy constructor a.x = 0  
x = 4067272
```

Why it is `a.x=0` and `x= 4067272`?

Comment: `x` is left uninitialized in the copy constructor.

Comment: And you return a reference to a temporary in `Fun`

Comment: @amitpandey007 - 1) Your copy constructor is bogus, as it doesn't do any copying.  2) Your fun() function invokes undefined behavior since you're returning the reference of a local object.  So your output could be anything -- it just so happens it is `0` and `4067272`.

Comment: Here is an example with fixed code:  http://ideone.com/xsBGZA

Answer (score 0):

Add code to initialize `x` in the copy constructor.

```
      A(const A &a) : x(a.x)
                  //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Missing code
      {
            cout<<"in copy constructor a.x = "<<a.x<<endl;
            cout<<" x = "<<x<<endl;
      }
```

Also,

`fun` returns a reference to a local variable. The reference is invalid after you return from `fun`. When you use `A t = fun(2);`, you are entering UB territory. You can't assume anything reasonable from it.

You can fix this by returning an object from `fun` instead of a `const&`.

```
  A fun(int i)
  {
      cout<<"in Fun"<<endl;
      A t(i+1);
      return(t);
  }
```

Comment: why a.x is zero? should it not be value in reference object?

Comment: `fun` returns a reference to a local variable. The reference is invalid after you return from `fun`. When you use `A t = fun(2);`, you are entering UB territory. You can't assume anything reasonable from it.